# proceeding in python code after omxplayer is called

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program with python on a raspberry pi that, when a button is pushed, an audio file is played. I have tried various methods of running omxplayer and then closing it properly, but none seem to work. My code is currently as follows:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep
import subprocess
BUTTON = 15
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
while True:
    if (GPIO.input(BUTTON)==True):
        a = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', '*.mp3'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
        sleep(1)
        a.stdin.write('q')
    if (/exit process/):
        #exit process
```

Currently, I receive an error in the a.stdin.write('q) line:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `a`, as in `a.subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a = subprocess.Popen

Comment: The error message is telling you what you have done wrong.

Comment: Piping `stdout` and `stderr` but not actually reading them may cause the external process to block. If you want the outputs ignored redirect them to the “null device“.  Use `os.devnull` for a platform independent name for that device file.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
a.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
```

or

```
a.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
```

instead of the `a.stdin.write('q')` line.

The error is because you are using python3 and can be fixed by using:

```
a.stdin.write(b'q')
```

Comment: Instead of downvoting actually inform me of what happened. Thereby users can give you further help, just in case you really want this answered..

Comment: The first two snippets use magic numbers instead of calling `terminate()` or `kill()` on the `Popen` instance.  `'q'.encode('utf-8')` is a bit complicated. Using a `bytes` literal (`b'q'`) would be simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the input. The `encode('utf-8')` really is too verbose.